# Source Code analyser Plugin (PMD,CheckStyle,FindBug) Compatibility Issue for RAD 7.5.3

Tags: compatibility, rad, findbugs, checkstyle, pmd

I am trying to add Java source code analyser plugins - PMD,Checkstyle & FindBug in Rational Application Developer 7.5.3 but I am getting some dependency issues and it's  not allowing me to install.The same is getting successfully installed in eclipse.

Please suggest whether I need to check for any particular versions for RAD or any other compatibility.

Thanks

Comment: RAD 7.5 is based on Eclipse 3.4.  Which is quite old.  Are you using versions of those plugins that are compatible with such an old version of Eclipse?

Comment: SonarQube is not compatible with Eclipse 3.4 (as far as I tried) and I am able to install PMD V3.0 now.Regarding checkstyle I couldn't get any other information. Will there be huge difference between PMD V3 and PMD V5.0 ? Will I be able to add the rules in V5.0 to V3.0 ? Please suggest.

Comment: PMD 3/4 is quite different from 5 under the hood.  The rules should be compatible though.  At least most of them.

Comment: Thanks Jeanne Boyarsky.

Comment: If possible upgrade to the latest version of RAD. It has improved integration with third party tools, including Checkstyle and FindBugs (See [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/e4210f90-a515-41c9-a487-8fc7d79d7f61/entry/third-party-plugins?lang=en)).